# htaccess redirection with Get and a twist

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, get

I'm trying to redirect urls generated by a form from

http://domain.co.uk/check.php?s=WUD092050549E to http://domain.co.uk/s/WUD092050549E.html

I've tried

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/s/$ check.php?s=$1
```

and

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^f/([^-]*)\.html$ /check.php?s=$1 [L]
```

To no success. I'm also wondering if there is a way to allow people to specify the format in the same url structure i.e

http://domain.co.uk/check.php?s=WUD092050549&format=json to 
http://domain.co.uk/s/WUD092050549E.json

---

*Edit*

I've come up with the below that appears to work with rewriting the urls back to what they once where

```
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$ 
RewriteRule ^([^.]+).([^?]+)$ /s/check.php?s=$1&format=$2
```

But I can't get it so when the form sends http://domain.co.uk/check.php?s=WUD092050549E&format=html it redirects to the pretty URL.

Comment: For your second example `http://domain.co.uk/s/WUD092050549E.json` do you want the contents of the page in json format or just a `.json` extension?

Comment: so I essentially want the format `http://domain.co.uk/s/{s}.{format}` where the parts in squiggly brackets are my varibles.

I can then use my script to output in the appropriate format.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work for you:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /check\.php\?s=(.*)&format=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /s/%2.%3\? [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^s/([\w-]+)\.(.+)$ check.php?s=$1&format=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```